# Que hace el Método jQuery submit () ?

Tags: jquery

Soy nuevo utilizando jQuery y estoy tratando de entender que hace este codigo, la unica duda que me queda es que no se que hace esta parte `$("#FORM").submit();`

```
function refrescar_reporte() {
    $.blockUI({ 
        css: { 
            border: 'none', 
            padding: '15px', 
            backgroundColor: '#000', 
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
            opacity: .5, 
            color: '#fff' 
            }
        , message: '<h1 class="cargando"><img src="images/cargando.gif"> Cargando...</h1>' 
    }); 

    $("#FORM").submit();
}
```

Comment: lo que hace ese evento es enviar el formulario. Es como si le dieras enviar con un botón de un formulario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La funcion `submit()` de jQuery sirve para manejar el evento de postear una forma o formulario.  En tu ejemplo estas explicitamente disparando dicho evento.  Tambien puedes manejarlo, ya que dicha funcion recibe un parametro opcional de una funcion.  Puedes leer mas en la documentacion:  https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 1):

Los formularios de html tienen un atributo que se llama **action**, y en él especificas la ruta a donde se enviará la información que el usuario ingrese en el formulario que estás trabajando.

Por ejemplo, si en tu formulario tienes el atributo action de la siguiente manera: **action="./server/guardarusuario.php"**, entonces al momento de enviarlo con el **submit()** de jQuery, el navegador enviará la información que tengas en los elementos del formulario (inputs, selects, options, entre otros elementos html) al archivo guardarusuario.php que especificaste en el atributo action del elemento  .

La desventaja de usar **submit()** es que recarga la página al momento de que se envía el formulario, por lo que para evitar esto es usar ajax como alternativa porque es asincrono y no tienes el inconveniente de que se recargue la página cuando se envié el formulario.

Espero haberte ayudado :)

Answer (score 1):

Como bien te ha explicado alanfcm el evento submit en jQuery se usa generalmente para validar formularios, submit() se lanza cuando se pulsa el input tipo submit de un formulario; pero como en tu ejemplo no se esta indicando ninguna acción al pulsar el botón, lo que estás haciendo es enviar el formulario.

Ejemplo para validar formulario:

```
$("#formulario").submit(function(){
     // Validacion del formulario
});
```

Comment: pulsa el boton [edit] y agregalo a la respuesta. mira [answer]